# How can i track COM+ events call with Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, com+

I have a huge application that was made with COM+ Objects and i want to track/log the call of events of these components. The objective is to find the problems and refator that methods.
I have found some documentation of API like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd179218(v=VS.85).aspx, but the only thing i could is to get the name of the pools in com+.

Comment: There's a sample which might be helpful [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289138(v=VS.71).aspx).

Comment: Thank's for link, but i can't get the data.

Comment: You can also download the sample [here](http://db.tt/tvvW9pwR).

Comment: Well, after some time, i am able not to access COM+ calls, but manage the COM+ objects subscriptions, it's a advance. Soon as possible, i will put the code on Github.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/926098) ETW can be used to trace COM and COM+. I'd be very interested to know if it works. Also note that ATL has a tracing/logging mechanism (ATLTRACE2) that may be of interest.

Comment: Sorry, i not in this jungle anymore. But thanks! It could be useful.